# How to get the value of an entry in a listView with context menus

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a contextmenu control on a listview, although I am trying to obtain the value of selected item in the listview when I right hand click on it - I have looked on numerous sources and have not found anything to convincing

```
private void startCheckToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: What does your code do at the moment? Can you post it?

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the sender to ListBox (assuming that's what was right clicked) and then you can iterate through selected items.

```
var lbx = sender as ListBox;
foreach (var item in lbx.SelectedItems) ...
```

[Hand keyed, so may be capitilization errors etc]

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                ListView listView = sender as ListView;
                this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
                if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(item.Text);
                        item.Selected = true;
                        contextMenuStrip1.Show(listView, e.Location);
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: ListView With ContextMenuStrip]